# Why is rapidjson giving me problems with std::string?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am trying to use an std::string with RapidJson

```cpp
using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;
const char* json = "{\n"
                   "    \"id\": null\n"
                   "    \"code\": null\n"
                   "}";
Document d;
string a = "myString";
d["myValue"].SetString(a); //error: no matching member function for call to 'SetString' in the compiler
```

I just want to be able to edit my json with rapidjson using std::string, but it is not working. New to c++ btw, so sorry if it is a stupid question.

Edit: I tried the solution from Jorge Perez, but I am still getting this error:

```
/include/rapidjson/document.h:1139: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>& rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::operator[](const rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>&) [with SourceAllocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `false' failed.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I do have a working json, I can use the other Set methods that Document has.

Comment: Not working in what way? Not compiling? Crashing at runtime? Something else? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is giving me the error before compiling, I just edited the question with some more code.

Comment: Personally, I'd use the nlohmann json library instead. Way simpler and easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string:

```
std::string s = "myString";
```

You can set it in RapidJson by using the data and size:

```
document["myValue"].SetString(s.data(), s.size(), document.GetAllocator());
```

Comment: I did that, now it is giving me ScrabbleClient: ../Downloads/rapidjson-master/include/rapidjson/document.h:1139: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>& rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::operator[](const rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>&) [with SourceAllocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `false' failed. Any ideas?

Comment: So @IvanSolis did you read what near the 1139 line inside ./Downloads/rapidjson-master/include/rapidjson/document.h ? Because there is a really nice [comment](http://rapidjson.org/document_8h_source.html) there on line 1105.